# how omitt header in xml file when appending info

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have an xml file created with `xmloutputter`.at the first time it is created it creates me the header but then I append info on it, I wouldn't the header.how can i omitt?

**EDIT**

```
            Element performances = new Element("performances");
            Document doc = new Document(performances);

            performances.setAttribute(new Attribute("date", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())));

            //Uptime
            Element uptime = new Element("uptime");
            uptime.addContent(new Element("days").setText(new Long(duptime).toString()));
            uptime.addContent(new Element("hours").setText(new Long(huptime).toString()));
            uptime.addContent(new Element("minutes").setText(new Long(muptime).toString()));
            uptime.addContent(new Element("seconds").setText(new Long(suptime).toString()));
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(uptime);
            //TotalHitsCount
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("totalhitcount").setText(new Long(stats.gettotal_hit_count()).toString()));
            //EmittedBytes
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("emittedbytes").setText(new Long(stats.getemitted_bytes()).toString()));
            //Avghitsec
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("avghitsec").setText(new Float(stats.getavg_hit_sec()).toString()));
            //Avgbyteshit
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("avgbyteshit").setText(new Long(stats.getavgbytes_hit()).toString()));
            //Avgbps
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("avgbps").setText(new Long(stats.getavgbps()).toString()));
            //Total threads
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("totalthreads").setText(new Long(stats.gettotal_threads()).toString()));
            //Idle threads
            doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("idlethreads").setText(new Long(stats.getidle_threads()).toString()));

            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

            xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter((String)path+"performances.xml",true));
```

Comment: What is xmloutputter?  It doesn't seem to be a class in the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want to do, because the xml format does not allow it.  an xml document has a *single* root level tag.  even if you do omit the xml header (which is certainly possible to do with most xml tools), your xml file will be invalid (i'm assuming you need to read this file from a standard xml parser).

your file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<performances>
  <update/>
  <!-- ... more xml elements ... -->
</performances>
<performances>
  <update/>
  <!-- ... appended xml elements ... -->
</performances>
```

and that is *not* a valid xml file.

in order to "append" to an xml file, you have to read the existing file and re-write it *entirely* with additional nodes.  a simple way to do that is to read the existing file into DOM using a DocumentBuilder, add your new nodes on to the existing root element, and re-write the entire xml file.

if you *truly* need to write the data in an appendable way, then i suggest using a file format other than xml (such as some sort of simple delimited flat file, e.g. CSV).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using this [method on Format](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#setOmitDeclaration%28boolean%29) and then this [constructor for XMLOutputter](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html#XMLOutputter%28org.jdom2.output.Format%29)?

```
    Element performances = new Element("performances");
    Document doc = new Document(performances);
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

    Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
    format.setOmitDeclaration(true);
    xmlOutput.setFormat(format);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    xmlOutput.output(doc, writer);
    System.out.println(writer);
```

gives `<performances />` in standard output with no XML declaration.

Comment: yes I tried but I'm not be able to call that method on format object...above my code